# Load Serialized File content int Text Boxes

Tags: java, swing, serialization, file-io, text-files

I am saving a Customer that extends a Person class into a text file. The details are written in different text boxes such as the Name and Surname of the Customer. When the text file is saved, the file is not readable but and the end the details are there. So I still don't know if its supposed to be saved this way... Assuming that its being saved correctly, I am trying to load the file saved and fill up the text boxes with the right content such as the Name and Surname of the customer. But when loading the file I get no Errors whatsoever like nothing happened or clicked. Need  a little bit of help since I'm new and don't know what I'm not doing right.

```
 private void savecustButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
     Customer customer = new Customer();
     try {
       FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Customers/" + custidTF.getText() + ".txt");
       ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

       customer.setPersonName((custnameTF.getText()));
       customer.setPersonSurname((custsurnameTF.getText()));
       customer.setPersonID((custidTF.getText()));

       oos.writeObject(customer);
       oos.close();
       fos.close();

       custnameTF.setText("");
       custsurnameTF.setText("");
       custidTF.setText("");

       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Person was Saved Successfully!",
         "Success", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

     } catch (IOException e) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Person could not be Saved!",
         "Error!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

       dispose();

     }
```

### loadCustomerActionPerformed

```
 private void loadCustomerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   Customer customerfile = null;
   try {

     final JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser("Customers/");
     int chooserOption = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
     chooserOption = JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION;

     File file = new File(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
     ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(
       new FileInputStream(file)
     );

     customerfile = (Customer) in .readObject();

     in .close();

   } catch (IOException ex) {
     System.out.println("Error loading file." + ex.getMessage());
   } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
     System.out.println("Invalid class in loaded file.");
   }

 }
```

### Person

```
public class Person implements Serializable {

  private String personName;
  private String personSurname;
  private String personID;
  private String personTel;
  private String personMob;

  public Person() {

    }
    /**
     * @return the personName
     */
  public String getPersonName() {
    return personName;
  }

  /**
   * @param personName the personName to set
   */
  public void setPersonName(String personName) {
    this.personName = personName;
  }

  /**
   * @return the personSurname
   */
  public String getPersonSurname() {
    return personSurname;
  }

  /**
   * @param personSurname the personSurname to set
   */
  public void setPersonSurname(String personSurname) {
    this.personSurname = personSurname;
  }

  /**
   * @return the personID
   */
  public String getPersonID() {
    return personID;
  }

  /**
   * @param personID the personID to set
   */
  public void setPersonID(String personID) {
    this.personID = personID;
  }
```

### Customer

```
public class Customer extends Person implements Serializable {

  private String consultant;

  /**
   * @return the consultant
   */
  public String getConsultant() {
    return consultant;
  }

  /**
   * @param consultant the consultant to set
   */
  public void setConsultant(String consultant) {
    this.consultant = consultant;
  }

}
```

Comment: May I ask what Javascript has to do with any of this?

Comment: are you executing the code in windows or linux

Comment: I'm executing the code on Windows

Comment: First things first, always close your resources in an `try...finally` block, never do what you are currently doing. The reason your load code doesn't do anything is because you haven't told it to do anything. You load your `Customer` then exit the method - you never set any text boxes to any values whatsoever.

Comment: please change the file location to "Customers\\"+....+"\\.txt");

Comment: @SaurabhJhunjhunwala don't talk nonsense please. Java is smart enough to work our the appropriate native delimiter given a path. The `String` constructor for `FileOutputStream` constructs a `File` with the appropriate path. `File` is platform independent, so that delimiter does not matter.

Comment: `File file = new File(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());`  would be better (and shorter) expressed as `File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();`

Comment: btw if `Customer implements Serializable` it is always better to specify a `serialVersionUID`

Comment: @BoristheSpider I did the finally clause and told it to print that the "  Customer File Loaded " and it printed it out but still the textboxes didnt fill up with the content

Comment: @Luke_i and so? You still load a `Customer` object, do nothing with it, then exit the method.

Comment: You need to individually set your blank fields custnameTF, custsurnameTF and custidTF using a setText() with the data you just read onto customerfile.